# Answers no longer sorted by score/votes

Tags: support, sorting, answer-order

For me at least, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002916/how-to-make-a-list-of-lists-using-a-str) has answers that are not sorted by score:

[image]

Is this normal?  I've tried refreshing the page a few times, but the order doesn't change...

Comment: On MSO: [Why are the answers out of order now?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261338/4642212).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You've selected the "Active" ordering for answers. If you want to sort by score, use the "Votes" ordering.

You change the sort order by selecting the appropriate tab, located on the line that says "X answers". The setting is sticky - it will keep the last selected sort order for all questions you browse from that point on.

> [image]

Comment: This solution does not work when the accepted answer has a lower score than other answers.  Is there a way to always sort by votes?

Comment: @Scott no, there isn't.