# Are answers no longer sorted by vote count

Tags: support, answers, sorting

I am not sure when this happened (or if its just my imagination), but lately I've been noticing that answers aren't sorted by their vote counts. I noticed this on couple of questions that I answered my question had the highest rating but wasn't on top. So was this feature never there and I was living in an illusion (in which case I apologize)? Or has something changed? I personally think sorting by upvotes count is a good idea.

Comment: There are tabs in the top right that change the sort order. They are "sticky", meaning that your setting persists across multiple pages. You probably accidentally clicked something other than "votes".

Comment: There are options to sort them by other things, but the default is by votes, with the accepted answer (if any, and if it isn't the OP's) at the top.

Comment: Even if you sort by vote score: 1) Accepted answers always top the list (except for self-accpets). 2) Answers may be out of order if they changed score or were just added while you were viewing the page; you can see them sorted by refreshing the page.

Comment: oh damn. so it was just me

Comment: I have noticed that as well. I also noticed that when you update your answer it goes right on top. **Before** [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18190714/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-excel/18190790#18190790) got accepted it kept going up and down **not** depending on the count. Once accepted it stabilized.

Comment: @mehow that's because the sort of answers having same score is random, by design. Every page reload will change the order. It's meant to prevent same answers stick on top and thus gain more votes and anyway, not relevant to this case.

Answer (score 2):

Below the question there are tabs that give you the option to change the sort order of the answers, choose votes for your desired order.
[image]

Comment: [Mat's circle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/191496/152859) is bigger. ;)

Comment: yeah. I see that now.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I think I did pretty well, considering I'm using a little touch pad on a laptop

Comment: For all we know, Mat might be using a little touch pad too. :D

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd [What's in the size of a free hand circle? that which we see as a free hand circle
By any other size would look as sweet;](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_rose_by_any_other_name_would_smell_as_sweet)

Comment: OK, you got my vote!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd sweet lol