# How many votes and flags are cast by users preferring particular answer order (active / oldest / votes)?

Tags: support, flags, voting, statistics, answer-order

Answers sort order ["sticks"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/191496/165773), meaning that system stores it somehow, so that it is possible to get statistics related to its usage.

I would like to know how many (percentage) of votes and flags are cast by users who prefer "active", "oldest" and "votes" sort order respectively.

I expect this to help me better understand how close is the perspective of those who *rate* content to that of those who *view* it (web search visitors see default order, which is by votes).

---

I am primarily interested in network wide stats (which are probably dominated by Stack Overflow) but if there are substantial site-specific deviations, I would like to learn about these as well.

Comment: For me, if I see a question with a lot (over 3(?)) answers, I'll tend to look at every one and will usually find one or two deserving of a flag (LOO, NAA, etc.). What I've seen is about one flag-worthy answer for every 7 or 8 "good" (not flag-worthy, but not necessarily great) ones

Comment: @ColeJohnson FWIW my personal favorite is "active" view (so that I don't need to scroll over older posts that I already voted at). I sometimes switch to other views but this happens rarely and doesn't last long. I asked for stats to learn if there's majority preference

Comment: ...and frankly, I hope to find out that most votes and flags are cast by folks using different (default) order. :) That would mean I can worry less about a bunch of quality issues that are "amplified" by my (active) sort order

Comment: very closely related: [How many users have changed their default Sort By?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237973/165773) The difference with my question is that requested statistics is for plain number of users instead of number of votes / flags

Comment: My guess would be those seeking answers sort by vote, while those seeking to help maintain content sort by active or oldest. I will switch sort order sometimes depending on the question, but in general when seeking answers I prefer it sorted by vote.